# display progress only when grids are getting loaded

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my application I have two drop downs. On changing the drop down selection I load multiple grids in a tree structure, but loading these grids takes some time (nearly 5 minutes to load all of them). Because of this, I have opted to show the loading progress using the code below:

Aspx code:

```
<form>
    <img style="visibility:hidden;" src="~/Image/loader.gif" runat="server" id="loading_image" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="121px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlYear_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="121px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlYear_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</form>
```

The problem with above code is the loading progress is always getting displayed, even after the grids are loaded. However I need to display the loading progress only for the time when grids are getting loaded, and once they have finished loading the loading progress should not appear. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use UpdateProgress tag

The DisplayAfter is milli-seconds and would run after specified seconds until the process is not complete.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress DynamicLayout="true" ID="upProgSearch" DisplayAfter="1500" runat="server"   >
    <ProgressTemplate>

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/images/Loading.gif" runat="server" />

    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: Try to add an event on dropdown called onchange and on the onchange event activate the updateprogress by using $('id').style.display = 'block';

Comment: Once the data is bound you can hide the updateprogress with display to be none, can do in code behind.

Comment: You need to use Ondatabound event in the grid not on the dropdown slected index, so on the parent grid can call onDataBound(which is last event you can get the id of the progressbar and set the style to be none)